# How to call a method in a Controller from a View and return objects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a MVC application which has a Controller that has a recursive method which returns an IEnumerable

```
public static IEnumerable<Category> GetSubCategoriesFor(int catId)
    {
        var subs = _db.Category.Where(c => c.parrent_id == catId);

        foreach (var sub in subs)
        {
            yield return sub;

            // Recursive call
            foreach (var subsub in GetSubCategoriesFor(sub.category_id))
            {
                yield return subsub;
            }
        }
```

The point is i need my view to show all Categories, subcategories and Questions in subcategories (It's a questionnarie)

So my question is, how can i call this method from my View??

I have seen some examples where they use Html.Action but i cannot iterate over a string or void

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `GetSubCategoriesFor` method seems to be flattening your hierarchical structure by returning a list which is mixing categories, subcategories, ...

Personally I would use display templates. For example if I have the following view model:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Questions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> Subcategories { get; set; }
}
```

I would populate it in the controller. In my example I have hardcoded the values for demonstration purposes but in your real example those values would obviously come from a database or something and they will be retrieved through a repository:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new[]
        {
            new CategoryViewModel
            {
                Id = 1,
                Questions = new[] { "q1.1", "q1.2" },
                Subcategories = new[]
                {
                    new CategoryViewModel
                    {
                        Id = 2,
                        Questions = new[] { "q2.1" }
                    },
                    new CategoryViewModel
                    {
                        Id = 3,
                        Questions = new[] { "q2.2", "q2.3" }
                    },
                }
            },
            new CategoryViewModel
            {
                Id = 4,
                Questions = new[] { "q1.3", "q1.4" },
                Subcategories = new[]
                {
                    new CategoryViewModel
                    {
                        Id = 5,
                        Questions = new[] { "q2.4" }
                    },
                }
            },
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and then my `~/Views/Home/Index.aspx` view will look like this:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<AppName.Models.CategoryViewModel>>" 
%>
<ul>
    <%= Html.DisplayForModel() %>
</ul>
```

and then I would define a display template for a category (`~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/CategoryViewModel.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Models.CanalViewModel>" 
%>
<li>
    <div>
        <h3><%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Id) %></h3>
        <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Questions) %>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Subcategories) %>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Now it is the ASP.NET MVC templated helpers that will take care of looping through the tree structure of categories and show the contents on the view. You could extend this further by defining a complex `QuestionViewModel` instead of the string I've used and by defining a display template for this question `~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/QuestionViewModel.ascx` it will be rendered for each element of the `Questions` property of a category.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will recursion work with this method? How many levels would it show, if a subcategory had subcategories for instance?

Comment: This is how my database model looks like: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/dbmodel.jpg/

Comment: @Nanek, the level of nesting that this method can handle is unlimited. You can have as many as you wish sub-sub-sub-sub categories :-)

Comment: How would i fill the ViewModel from my controller? If you look at the link i provided you can see the class names. I use the entity framework to load my database. Sorry for my ignorance

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have an unknown amount of iterations then you would need to use a HTML Helper.

[Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx)